# Micro thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

It is possible to reserve memory per thread in application with using std library? I want to create some micro threads and I would like to know how to reserve memory per thread and if it is possible what are the best practices to allocation memory for threads.

Comment: The standard supports thread-local memory.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: The memory allocated by any thread is accessible by any other thread, that's right. But if only one thread has the pointer to this memory, then he will be the only thread that accesses it. Thread-local memory is only needed when the same function/object is accessed by multiple threads, and you need to handle/store values per thread there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use thread local storage if you need some static memory different for every thread but with the same pointer:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

static thread_local char thread_name[40]; // on older compilers use __thread

void thread1() {
    strcpy(thread_name, "T1");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
       std::cerr << thread_name << ": I'm thread1!\n";
}

void thread2() {
    strcpy(thread_name, "T2");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
       std::cerr << thread_name << ": I'm thread2!\n";
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(thread1), t2(thread2);
  t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

... or you can allocate your memory dynamically (with new, malloc....) inside the thread function in a local variable, in both ways the other threads will not be able to access it.

Usually when yo write a function or a module that uses only private memory and does not alter the program state that function/module is said to be **reentrant**.

Comment: Why a compiler extension instead of a `thread_local` variable?

Comment: You are right, I pasted it from GCC 4.4 compatible code, I edited my answer.